# "Двойное дно" — этимология, значение и использование фразеологизма

Tags: этимология, фразеология, выбор-слов, значение-слов

В одной из популярных (околонаучных) телепередач прозвучало такое высказывание:
**Многие факты могут иметь двойное дно.**

Отсюда возникли вопросы:
1. Когда появилось это выражение?
2. Что оно означает? У кого-чего имеется второе дно?
3. Правильно ли использовано в указанном предложении?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Двойное дно** - метафора, указывающая на наличие *скрытого смысла, подвоха или обманчивой видимости*. Буквально она отсылает к "**чемодану с двойным дном**" из старых фильмов о шпионах и контрабандистах - они прятали под вторым дном оружие, шпионские приспособления или наркотики. От уподобления чего-либо чемодану с двойным дном со временем произошёл сдвиг к укороченному выражению "**с двойным дном**" или ссылками на наличие "**двойного дна**". Менее широко известно "двойное дно" как *термин* в кораблестроении, геологии (второе дно водоёмов) и экономике.

Установить время начала использования выражения трудно, но приблизительно можно проследить его по изданиям словарей. У *Даля* такого упоминания нет (хотя *ящики с двойным дном* у фокусников были известны много веков), в *Малом академическом словаре* есть "чемодан с двойным дном" в статье "дно", а у *Ожегова* уже есть метафора "**человек с двойным дном**". Можно предположить, что современное употребление выражения связано с развитием средств массовой информации во 2 половине 20 века (кино и телевидение), а само возникновение штампа с уже "потерянным" чемоданом произошло с лёгкой руки какого-нибудь журналиста. Сейчас так говорят даже литературные критики, которые находят "*метафоры с двойным дном*" у поэтов.

Чтобы понять смысл *двойного дна у фактов* (в нейтральном это смысле или о "скелетах в шкафу"), нужен контекст, но само по себе выражение возможно: известный факт - видимость, а за ним может скрываться что-либо интересное или зловещее.